# Change list to immutable object

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

As you can see input `data` and output `my_data` is mutable objects, how can I make `my_data` immutable and still have the possibility to iterate on it? (basically same behavior) use another dataclass?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

data = {'demo1': "description for demo 1", "demo2": 'description for demo 2'}

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class SomeDataclass:
    name: str
    description: str



class ParserClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.my_data = []

    def parsing_method(self, demo_data) -> None:
        for data, description in demo_data.items():
            self.my_data.append(SomeDataclass(name=data, description=description))

test = ParserClass()
test.parsing_method(data)
for my_date in test.my_data:
    print(my_date.name, my_date.description)
```

Comment: Convert the `list` to a `tuple` once it has been populated with data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your parser is a class, you can turn any of its attributes into read only attributes with [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

```
class ParserClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._my_data = []

    @property
    def my_data(self):
        return self._my_data.copy()  # copy to pass a new list, not the one in the parser

    def parsing_method(self, demo_data) -> None:
        for data, description in demo_data.items():
            self._my_data.append(SomeDataclass(name=data, description=description))
```

NB. as list are mutable, we are using `copy` to keep the private `_my_data` read-only, the returned copy can be modified (e.g. `inst.my_data.append(something)`), but that will not be reflected on the original private `_my_data`.

Or with @match's suggestion:

```
class ParserClass:
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._my_data = tuple()

    def parsing_method(self, demo_data) -> None:
        tmp_data = []
        for data, description in demo_data.items():
            tmp_data.append(SomeDataclass(name=data, description=description))
        self.my_data = tuple(tmp_data)
```

Comment: A problem with the first approach is that `test.my_data.append("x")` will silently fail to do anything.

Comment: That’s true. I’ll update ASAP.

Comment: Not saying I would change it, just wanted to highlight the limitation. It may be a good solution for some especially as it's simple to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can simply convert them to tuples by using **tuple()** function. Tuple is immutable and iterable.

Edit: Someone else suggested it in a reply to your question when I was typing this. But I'll just leave it here